# Regex for Hashtag but only return true if 5 or more hashtags are in the String

Tags: python, pandas, count

There's a few different ways of using Regex for hashtags that I've been able to find:

- `(#[a-z0-9_]+)`
- `(#+[a-zA-Z0-9(_)]{1,})`

I have some data where there might be too many hashtags or @ symbols present. Really simply: if I had more than 5 hashtags present in a String, I'd like to be able to drop the row in Pandas. I thought it wouldn't be that hard, maybe something like `(#[A-z0-9_]+){5,}` but that doesn't work. Is this possible with Regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`pandas.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to to count occurrences of pattern in each string of the Series.

```py
out = df[df['col'].str.count('#[a-z0-9_]+').le(5)]
```

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'hashtag': ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '#1#2#3#4#5#6']})

out = df[df['hashtag'].str.count('#[a-z0-9_]+').le(5)]
```

```
print(out)

  hashtag
0       5
1       6
2       7
3       8
4       9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) the values and use it for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 5
df[df['col'].str.count('#[a-z0-9_]+').le(N)]
```

example:

```
# input
                                             col
0  #abc blah #def #ghi blah #jk_1 blah #lmn     
1  #abc blah #def #ghi blah #jk_1 blah #lmn #opq
2  #abc #def                                    

# output
                                         col
0  #abc blah #def #ghi blah #jk_1 blah #lmn 
2  #abc #def
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['#abc blah #def #ghi blah #jk_1 blah #lmn ',
                           '#abc blah #def #ghi blah #jk_1 blah #lmn #opq',
                           '#abc #def']})
```

Comment: perfect! Just would change the regex itself to `A-z0-9_` to include capitalized words.

Comment: @kabaname yes, you can tweak the regex as you want, you could also use `'(?i)#[a-z0-9_]+'` for case insensitive ;)